# How to target the user in android firebase custom notification in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBO74.png)

i want to create same multiple custom target key for targeting the       user?

i attached the sample image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: thank you for your response , i already attached the sample image.

Comment: Could you clarify your use case? Do you want to use the conditions in the screenshot when sending from your server?